# Choosing 20 points of out a square

Tags: probability, geometry, independence

From a square $[0,2]\times[0,2]$ we choose randomly and independently 20 points. Let X denote number of points chose which are not in a square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Calculate expected value and variance of variable X. How should i approach this question? I have no idea how to even start it.

Comment: It is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $B(n,p)$ with number of trials $n = 20$ and prob. of success for each trial $p = 3/4$. Look at the wiki page for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $S$ denote the small square. The probability that a point is in $X$ is one minus the probability that it is in $S$.

Draw a picture to figure out what the probability that a point is in $S$ is.